# Poll/select copying to kernelspace from userspace

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, select

Why do we need to copy data from user space to kernel space when calling poll/select if in kernel mode CPU can access user space memory?

Quote from Linux Programming Interface:

> When running in user mode, the CPU can access only memory that is marked as being in user space; attempts to access memory in kernel space result in a hardware exception. When running in kernel mode, the CPU can access both user and kernel memory space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this is done to avoid complications such as:

1. security (multiple threads)
2. user space can be swapped out anytime

There are a few advancements such as [splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_(system_call)) that help in certain circumstances (where copying is avoided as much as possible)

Here's an article that talks about how to perform Zero Copy operations during file read/writes: [Zero Copy I: User-Mode Perspective](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6345)

Comment: How does multi thread affect security?